# Preventing CSS from affecting child views

Tags: html, css, view

In the context of .NET MVC (but that could also apply to other similar technologies), let :

1. A tree of views, e.g the page view `FileUploadPage` and its child partial view `FileDropZone` that would have a class identifying their view "type" on their root node :

FileUploadPage.cshtml :

```
<div class="view-fileuploadpage">
    <h2>File upload page view</h2>
    @Html.Partial("FileDropZone")
</div>
```

FileDropZone.cshtml :

```
<div class="view-filedropzone">
    File drop zone partial view
</div>
```

2. Some CSS rules which I would like to apply only to the view's own elements instead of globally :

Like this :

```
.view-fileuploadpage h2 {
    /* Spécific to the view FileUploadPage */
}
```

But **NOT** like this :

```
h2 {
    /* Global, not what I want */
}
```

I like this way of doing things, because it prevents interferences from other pages in the CSS due to needlessly global selectors.

However there is a problem with that : the view-specific CSS rules apply to the view's own elements, but also to any other view that is being included as a child view. In the example above, the view `FileDropZone` inherits the rules that are supposed to be specific to the view `FileUploadPage`, which is an undesired consequence.

**So my question is : how can I make the CSS rules that are supposed to be specific to my views own elements NOT apply to the child views as well ?**

I could use the "direct child" opeartor in my selectors to specify the full "path" to the elements I want to style, like so :

```
.view-fileuploadpage > h2 {
    /* Applies to the h2 of the view FileUploadPage */
    /* DOes NOT apply to any h2 that would exist in a child view of FileUploadPage */
}
```

But this would make the code hard to maintain, because the selectors would have to be updated every time a piece of markup gets moved or modified within a view.

I'm having the exact same problem with JavaScript and query selectors, but I guess finding a solution for CSS would also solve the JavaScript problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/#:%7E:text=Negation%20Pseudo%2Dclass,in%20this%20case.) pseudo-class to deselect grandchildren within a particular child.

```
.view-fileuploadpage h2:not(.file-drop-zone *):not(.more-children *){
  color: #f00;
  }
```

This assigns the color to all `h2` elements excluding those in the stated classes within the `:not()` selector.

The CSS file will need to be updated with the classes of new children if any.

The best solution will be to wrap all the contents of the `view-fileuploadpage` or parent div that should not get the styling and use the class of this wrapper as a single selector. This way, the file will not need constant updating all future children and grandchildren are added within the wrapper.

Hence, instead of having:

```
    <div class='view-fileuploadpage-one'>
      <h2>Container</h2>
      <p>...</p>
     
      <div class='file-drop-zone'>
        <h2>file drop zone</h2>
        ...
      </div>
    
      <div class='more-children'>
        <h2>More children</h2>
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
```

You can opt for:

```
 <div class='view-fileuploadpage-two'>
    <h2>Container</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class='content-wrapper'>
    <!--   this wrapper will contain everything else -->
      <div class='file-drop-zone'>
        ...
      </div>

      <div class='more-children'>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Which will be more or less:

```
<div class='view-fileuploadpage-two'>
    ...
  <div class='content-wrapper'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly see my idea on [this pen](https://codepen.io/somtoChukwun/pen/dydwewp).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using the `:not` is smart, but as you say, would require to much maintenance to suit my needs. Also it would not work with nested views of the same view type (e.g if I wanted to embed a view A within another view A).
I'm trying to understand your second solution, but your pen does not seem to contain that second solution entirely as I don't see the `wrapper` class involved in any selector.
Is your idea to flatten the view hierarchy by putting all the views of the view tree at the same level, as children of a unique wrapper ? Am I understanding this right ? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer and the pen. Yes, my second solution more or less reflects your explanation of modifying the hierarchy.

Comment: Ho I think I understand. You want to use this "wrapper" class to identify child views regardless of their actual name/class, so that the CSS doesn't need to evolve, I get it. Unfortunately I cannot change the structure of my view tree however I want. What I can do on the other hand is wrap each one of my child view inclusions with such a class, from the parent view, to exclude them. Like `<div class="A"><div class="childOfA">@Partial("ChildView")</div></div> and then ignore anything in childOfA`. I will dig into that. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: That's a great idea. You can simply add an extra class to each of the containers that should not have the styles. I have updated my solution with this third option to make it plain for other interested parties. Thanks

Comment: So after some experimentation, it turns out that the class name used to wrap the included child view has to be specific to the parent view and not be a generic one. If it's a generic one (like "child-view" for example), it will also exclude from the resultats the elements of the view we want to search, because that view as well is also gonna be included in the same way. However, if the class name is specific to the view, like "child-of-someviewname", then this same class name will not appear at a higher higher in the DOM and thus will not exclude the elemnts of the view (unless recursive view)